# Different version of Php 7.x

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, php-7.2, php-7.3

I have different version of Php on my laravel homestead. If i lunch php -v on command bash i have active php 7.3 but if i create and index.php with phpinfo() i have this 'PHP Version 7.2.14-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1'

php -v

> HP 7.3.1-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2019
>   10:19:33) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.3.1, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.3.1-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.7.0beta1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
>       with blackfire v1.24.2~linux-x64-non_zts73, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfire

in my index.php

```
phpinfo();
```

i have

> PHP Version 7.2.14-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

I want to use only php 7.3 how can i do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ubuntu users this should work (with apache)

```
sudo a2dismod php7.X
sudo a2enmod php7.3
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Witn nginx in your .conf change the version for fastcgi

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
service nginx restart
```

Comment: i don't use  a2dismod beacause homesead is an ngnix server.  i have this result: ERROR: Module php7.2 does not exist!
ERROR: Module sudo does not exist!
ERROR: Module a2enmod does not exist!
ERROR: Module php7.3 does not exist!
ERROR: Module sudo does not exist!
ERROR: Module service does not exist!
ERROR: Module apache2 does not exist!
ERROR: Module restart does not exist!

Comment: Elliot your answer would work on a non-Laravel Homestead installation but it's not relevant for Laravel Homestead. To avoid downvotes it might be best to remove this as an answer because it's technically wrong.